# MySQL - A conditional WHERE

Tags: mysql

See, I've got this bulletin board. This query here works just fine.

```
    SELECT bulletin.date,
        bulletin.title,
        bulletin.content,
        bulletin.id,
        bulletin.made_by,
        users.ID,
        users.name
    FROM bulletin, users
    WHERE bulletin.id = '12345'
        AND bulletin.made_by = users.ID
    LIMIT 1
```

Now, I'm running into troubles because when a user deletes his account there is no information about said person left, he is deleted from the users table. I know there may be other ways to deal with this but I can't fix that now.

So I ask: How can I make that query return bulletin.date, bulletin.title and bulletin.content where bulletin.id is equal to 12345 even though I've got "AND bulletin.made_by = users.ID"? You see, I need to have that for all the other posts where the user still exists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT b.date,
       b.title,
       b.content,
       b.id,
       b.made_by,
       b.ID,
       b.name
FROM bulletin b
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on b.made_by = u.ID
WHERE b.id = '12345'
LIMIT 1
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks! And that really is a great explanation in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are using `INNER JOIN`, Use `LEFT JOIN` in order to solve your problem.

```
SELECT a.date,
       a.title,
       a.content,
       a.id,
       a.made_by,
       a.ID,
       a.name
FROM bulletin a
         LEFT JOIN users c
           ON a.made_by = c.ID
WHERE a.id = '12345'
LIMIT 1
```

`LEFT JOIN` basically fetches all the records from the `left` table whether it has a matching row in the second table or not.